# Add company field in Customer grid in admin

Tags: adminhtml, customer

I have added "Company" field in admin customer grid, but the issue i face is sorting not working.

I have override Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid Class and added below code:

```
 protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        parent::_prepareCollection();

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('company')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_company', 'customer_address/company', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left'); 

        $this->setCollection($collection); 

        return $this;
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {


        $this->addColumn('company', array(
            'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Company'),
            'width'     =>  '150',
            'index'     =>  'billing_company',

        )); 
        $this->addColumnsOrder('billing_company', 'email');
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
```

Can anyone have solution for above issue?

Comment: I think you need to put filter index if sorting is not working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that Magento does a lot of required work on the collection in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection()`, that is, when you call `parent::_prepareCollection()` at the beginning of your overwritten method.
What happens is

1. You call the original parent `_prepareCollection()`
2. The original collection is initialized
   in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid::_prepareCollection()`
3. The collection is assigned to the grid
   `$this->setCollection()`
4. The abstract parent grid `_prepareCollection()` is called.
5. During this method call, the order is applied, which at this point in time is the default order since the collection hasn't got the `company` or `billing_company` attribute in it's select list yet.
   `$this->_setCollectionOrder($this->_columns[$columnId]);`
6. After the parents `_prepareCollection()` method finished, you instantiate a new customer collection, and add all the attributes you want to display, and assign it to the grid.
7. The order isn't reapplied, since you don't call the abstract grids `_prepareCollection` again.

Which you can't, since calling `parent::_prepareCollection()` would once again override your collection with the original one.

One possible solution would be to duplicate the logic from the abstract grid's `_prepareCollection()` method, but copying code is always bad for maintainability.

A better solution is to look for a suitable hook method, that gives you the chance to add your new company column to the **existing** collection **before** the sort order and filtering is applied.

Looking at the first few lines of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection()` we can see just what we need:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    if ($this->getCollection()) {

        $this->_preparePage();
```

So, instead of overwriting the `protected function _prepareCollection()` in your block, try this instead:

```
protected function _preparePage()
{
    $this->getCollection()
        ->joinAttribute('billing_company', 'customer_address/company', 'default_billing', null, 'left');
    return parent::_preparePage();
}
```

It's all a matter of timing and inserting the custom logic at the right point during the process flow.