# I can't add custom attribute to sales grid

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, adminhtml, custom-options, grid

This is my attribute, which works ok

```
    $installer->addAttribute("customer", "limit_kredytowy",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "limit kredytowy",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "limit_kredytowy");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();
```

Now, I make new column in Adminhtml customer grid block

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('numer_klienta', array(
           'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Numer Klienta'),
           'index' => 'numer_klienta',
           'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_addEGColumnFilter'),
    ));
```

But it show empty column

[image]

Can you guys help me. Ofcourse i'm noob.

Full Grid.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Adminhtml customer grid block
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('customerGrid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('numer_klienta', array(
               'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Numer Klienta'),
               'index' => 'numer_klienta',
               'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_addEGColumnFilter'),
        ));
        $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ID'),
            'width'     => '50px',
            'index'     => 'entity_id',
            'type'  => 'number',
        ));
        /*$this->addColumn('firstname', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('First Name'),
            'index'     => 'firstname'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('lastname', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Name'),
            'index'     => 'lastname'
        ));*/
        $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Name'),
            'index'     => 'name'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('email', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Email'),
            'width'     => '150',
            'index'     => 'email'
        ));

        $groups = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', array('gt'=> 0))
            ->load()
            ->toOptionHash();

        $this->addColumn('group', array(
            'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
            'width'     =>  '100',
            'index'     =>  'group_id',
            'type'      =>  'options',
            'options'   =>  $groups,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('Telephone', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Telephone'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'index'     => 'billing_telephone'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_postcode', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ZIP'),
            'width'     => '90',
            'index'     => 'billing_postcode',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_country_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Country'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'type'      => 'country',
            'index'     => 'billing_country_id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_region', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('State/Province'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'index'     => 'billing_region',
        ));

        /*$this->addColumn('customer_since', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer Since'),
            'type'      => 'datetime',
            'align'     => 'center',
            'index'     => 'created_at',
            'gmtoffset' => true
        ));*/

        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('website_id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Website'),
                'align'     => 'center',
                'width'     => '80px',
                'type'      => 'options',
                'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getWebsiteOptionHash(true),
                'index'     => 'website_id',
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '100',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'    => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Edit'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                        'field'     => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
        ));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('customer')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Excel XML'));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('customer');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
             'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Delete'),
             'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
             'confirm'  => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Are you sure?')
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('newsletter_subscribe', array(
             'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Subscribe to Newsletter'),
             'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massSubscribe')
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('newsletter_unsubscribe', array(
             'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Unsubscribe from Newsletter'),
             'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massUnsubscribe')
        ));

        $groups = $this->helper('customer')->getGroups()->toOptionArray();

        array_unshift($groups, array('label'=> '', 'value'=> ''));
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('assign_group', array(
             'label'        => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Assign a Customer Group'),
             'url'          => $this->getUrl('*/*/massAssignGroup'),
             'additional'   => array(
                'visibility'    => array(
                     'name'     => 'group',
                     'type'     => 'select',
                     'class'    => 'required-entry',
                     'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
                     'values'   => $groups
                 )
            )
        ));

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=> true));
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id'=>$row->getId()));
    }
}
```

Comment: have you got this field in collection of sales?

Comment: $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

Comment: just see below answer

Comment: Zydol,check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912192/magento-custom-customer-attribute-to-show-in-grid/21913429#21913429

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused as your attribute has the code `limit_kredytowy` yet you add the column `numer_klienta`. So the basics of adding a column to the customer grid are as follows.

1. Add the attribute and fill in some values,
2. Add the column in the grid,
3. Add the column in the collection's select,

**Add the attribute and fill in some values**

You seem to have this working via the set-up script and have added the attribute to be used in forms. This will mean that you can add the values in the admin section.

**Add the column in the grid**

What you can do here is rewrite the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid` via the following config.xml

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <customer_grid>Your_Module_Block_Customer_Grid<customer_grid>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Now you need to rewrite the function `_prepareColumns` so that you add your own column.

```
$this->addColumn('your_custom_attribute', array(
       'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Your Custom Attribute'),
       'index' => 'your_custom_attribute',
));
```

**Add the column in the collection's select**

Now you need to rewrite the function `_prepareCollection` and add your column to the select.

```
->addAttributeToSelect('your_custom_attribute')
```

For more information about adding items to customer grid I suggest [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/5973/158)

Answer (score -2):

Please Make sure that this an example don't change directly on core file please rewrite your class tjen do changes.

We are going to first copy the core file to a local directory, then code a bit. Copy

`/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php` to `/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php`.

First, to make custom attribute available for inserting to grid we need to modify _prepareCollection function. Here, we are working with database table fields and using SQL joins. Let`s suppose that we need to add a postcode column. Search for _prepareCollection function and simply add this line:

so function will look like:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',array('customer'));
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

As you can see, we have joined the sales_flat_order_address table that stores the postcode field. To insert this column into the order grid, edit _prepareColumns() function. Here you can see how default columns are inserted, so using the addColumn method, we add our own `customer` column.

```
    $this->addColumn('customer', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer'),
        'index' => 'postcode',
    ));
enter preformatted text here
```

Comment: Ok, I have /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

Comment: I put it on firt question

Comment: And my custom attributa is "numer_klienta"

Comment: error, have white page on backend/customer/manage customer :(

Comment: Some progres, when I sort my custom column "numer klienta" then attribute is showing, but when I sort some off others column, my attribute disappears. What the f...