# custom manage products admin panel shipping weights

Tags: admin, custom, admin-panel, grid

Does anyone know how I can add a weight column to the Catalog, Manage Products, Admin Panel? ID, NAME, TYPE-ATTRIB. SET NAME, SKU, PRICE, QTY, VISIBILITY, STATUS, ***WEIGHT***

Comment: Did you try Google?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can write a simple module in fifteen minutes that will do this for you (without rewrites)

Thanks to @Narno for his answer: [Adding columns to customer grid using observer or overriding the customer grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5973/adding-columns-to-customer-grid-using-observer-or-overriding-the-customer-grid/5986#comment25795_5986)

I added some slight modifications so it should work for the products grid.

The Observers way:

Declare 2 observers in your config.xml file: one to add your column to the grid block and the other one to load data from the corresponding attribute:

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
       <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
         <observers>
            <{observer_name}>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>{namespace}_{module}/observer</class>
                <method>beforeBlockToHtml</method>
            </{observer_name}>
        </observers>
    </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
    <eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
        <observers>
            <{observer_name}>
                <class>{namespace}_{module}/observer</class>
                <method>beforeCollectionLoad</method>
            </{observer_name}>
        </observers>
    </eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
  </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Create an Observer class with appropriate methods:

```
 class {Namespace}_{Module}_Model_Observer
{
public function beforeBlockToHtml(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getBlock();


    if ($block->getType() == 'adminhtml/catalog_product_grid') {
       $block->addColumnAfter('status', array(
                    'header'    => 'Name to show on top',
                    'type'      => 'text',
                    'index'     => 'weight',
                ), 'sku');
    }
}

public function beforeCollectionLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    if (!isset($collection)) {
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
     */
    if ($collection instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection) {
        /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('weight');
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will need to rewrite the block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` and make the following changes.

1. Rewrite the function `_prepareCollection` so that it adds the attribute `weight` to the select,
2. Rewrite the function `_prepareColumns` so that a new column is added to the grid for the attribute `width`