# Magento Customer Grid - Last Order Date

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-grid

I'm trying to add some extra columns into Magento's customer grid.
I've got an order count working successfully (Total amount of orders a customer has placed)

I'm trying to get the Last Order date in, but I'm unable to get it working.
Has anyone done this before or can someone point me in the right direction as to how to do this?

This is my current code, but it errors and just displays a SQL query.

```
    $orderTableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
        ->getTableName('sales/order');
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(
            array('orders' => $orderTableName),
            'orders.customer_id=e.entity_id',
            array(
                'order_count' => 'COUNT(customer_id)',
                'last_order' => 'MAX(created_at)'
            )
        );
    $collection->groupByAttribute('entity_id');
```

Comment: have edited the answer. You may try the subselect solution.

Comment: small advice: upvote good answers and downvote poor answers. this encourage frequent site visitors to help you from one side and helps the whole community to grow in the right direction.

Comment: Have edited the answer: added working code example

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful :-) 
I'm also using your Customer Attributes Extension - Is it possible to get attributes onto the Invoice Grid?

Comment: probably yes, but not sure. For http://amasty.com/customer-attributes.html you'd better email us directly and me or my colleagues will help you.  Reference to this question even if your free support period is over.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is working example for CE 1.8.1:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addNameToSelect()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');



    // add 2 new fields as sub queries      
    $sql ='SELECT MAX(o.created_at)'
        . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o'
        . ' WHERE o.customer_id = e.entity_id ';
    $expr = new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $sql . ')'); 

    $collection->getSelect()->from(null, array('last_order_date'=>$expr));

    $sql ='SELECT COUNT(*)'
        . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o'
        . ' WHERE o.customer_id = e.entity_id ';
    $expr = new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $sql . ')'); 

    $collection->getSelect()->from(null, array('orders_count'=>$expr));

    //echo $collection->getSelect(); exit;      

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

and

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ID'),
        'width'     => '50px',
        'index'     => 'entity_id',
        'type'  => 'number',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('last_order_date', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Order Date'),
        'type'      => 'datetime',
        'align'     => 'center',
        'index'     => 'last_order_date',
        'gmtoffset' => true,        
    ));

    $this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Orders Count'),
        'index'     => 'orders_count',
    ));

    ........
    ........
```

The output is

[image: orders]

Comment: I had already tried MAX(created_at) Sorry - I'll update my Question

Comment: Good solution...........:)

Comment: I've added this code before $this->setCollection($collection);
Then set "last_oder" in my addColumn code but it seems to be blank :(

Comment: Perfect!
I will award the bounty in 19 hours when I'm able to :-)

Comment: Filter does not work with above code.

Comment: Also sorting does not work.

Comment: Alright, this works PERFECTLY! Does anybody know how to show only the count for orders with statuses "complete" and "processing"? Thanks!

Comment: Found the solution, sharing it here in case someone else needs the same thing (I don't see why we should take into account anything else than the completed orders). I added ` . ' AND o.status LIKE  "complete" ' ` after ` . ' WHERE o.customer_id = e.entity_id '; `

Comment: For search you can create custom call back function see http://newsinfo-blog.blogspot.com/2016/10/add-order-details-column-in-customer.html

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I would do this.
I would create 2 attributes called `last_order_date` and `orders_count` on the customer entity that are only visible in the backend. Or not visible at all.  [Here is one possible way to add them](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14165/146).

The I would create an observer on the `checkout_submit_all_after` event that would change the values of these attributes.
Something like this:

```
public function checkoutSubmitAllAfter($observer) {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    if ($order) { //if on onepage checkout;
        $customer = $order->getCustomer();
        $lastOrderDate = $order->getCreatedAt();
        $increment = 1;
    }
    else { //if on multishipping checkout
       $orders = $observer->getEvent()->getOrders();
       //get last order that's the important one;
       $order = $orders[count($orders) - 1];
       $customer = $order->getCustomer();
       $lastOrderDate = $order->getCreatedAt();
       $increment = count($orders);
    }
    if ($customer && $customer->getId()) { //check if the customer is logged in
       //make sure you have a clean instance of the customer
       //this line may not be needed. Test with it and without it.
       $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId());
       //set the new values on the customer entity
       $customer->setLastOrderDate($lastOrderDate);
       $customer->setOrdersCount((int)$customer->getOrdersCount() + $increment);
       $customer->save();
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the code, so I may have missed something.

Now you have the values you need on the customer object and you don't need any crazy join or sort order and specially no `group by`.
You can [add your 2 new columns](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5986/146) in the customer grid and you can even make them sortable and filterable easily.

If you already have customers in your db, then you will need a one time only script that sets the values for the existing customers.
But you can identify these values easily.

Comment: Small side note: `checkout_submit_all_after` works great for visitors, but I think for admin orders you need one more event.

Comment: @Amasty. Nope. That's all you need. The event is there in the backend also. Check `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create::createOrder`. It's the last line before the `return`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved the problem with filter and ordering working, `_prepareCollection`:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->addNameToSelect()
    ->joinAttribute('billing_street', 'customer_address/street', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
;

$sql = sprintf('SELECT MAX(o.created_at) AS created_at FROM %s AS o GROUP BY o.customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order_grid'));
$expr = new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $sql . ')');

$collection->joinTable(array('order' => 'sales/order_grid'), 'customer_id=entity_id', array('order_created_at' => 'created_at'), "order.created_at IN ($expr)", 'left');
```

Then on `_prepareColumns`:

```
$this->addColumn('order_created_at', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
    'type'      => 'datetime',
    'index'     => 'order_created_at',
    'gmtoffset' => true,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only "complete" status like me, then just add `. ' AND o.status LIKE  "complete" '` after `. ' WHERE o.customer_id = e.entity_id ';`

I've also added the total Money spent by the customer (so the total of all of it's complete orders)

```
    $total_pricesql ='SELECT sum(o.base_grand_total)'
        . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o'
        . ' WHERE o.customer_id = e.entity_id ' . ' AND o.status LIKE  "complete" ';
    $expr = new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $total_pricesql . ')'); 

    $collection->getSelect()->from(null, array('total_price'=>$expr));
```

and later in the same file

```
    $this->addColumn('total_price', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total'),
        'index' => 'total_price',
        'type'  => 'number',
        'filter'    => false,
    ));
```

so change @Amasty's first codes:

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->addNameToSelect()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');



// add 3 new fields as sub queries      
$sql ='SELECT MAX(o.created_at)'
    . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o'
    . ' WHERE o.customer_id = e.entity_id ' . ' AND o.status LIKE  "complete" ';
$expr = new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $sql . ')'); 

$collection->getSelect()->from(null, array('last_order_date'=>$expr));

$sql ='SELECT COUNT(*)'
    . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o'
    . ' WHERE o.customer_id = e.entity_id ' . ' AND o.status LIKE  "complete" ';
$expr = new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $sql . ')'); 

$collection->getSelect()->from(null, array('orders_count'=>$expr));

$total_pricesql ='SELECT sum(o.base_grand_total)'
    . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o'
    . ' WHERE o.customer_id = e.entity_id ' . ' AND o.status LIKE  "complete" ';
$expr = new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $total_pricesql . ')'); 

$collection->getSelect()->from(null, array('total_price'=>$expr));

//echo $collection->getSelect(); exit;      

$this->setCollection($collection); return parent::_prepareCollection();}
```

and the second code:

```
protected function _prepareColumns() {
$this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ID'),
    'width'     => '50px',
    'index'     => 'entity_id',
    'type'  => 'number',
));

$this->addColumn('last_order_date', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Order Date'),
    'type'      => 'datetime',
    'align'     => 'center',
    'index'     => 'last_order_date',
    'gmtoffset' => true,        
));

$this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Orders Count'),
    'index'     => 'orders_count',
));

$this->addColumn('total_price', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total'),
    'index' => 'total_price',
    'type'  => 'number',
    'filter'    => false,
));

........
........
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case - Added 3 new columns to ***Admin Customer Grid***

1. **orders total**
2. **orders count**
3. **last order date**

Added following changes to *app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php*

---

Changed method **_setCollectionOrder**

```
protected function _setCollectionOrder($column)
{
    if (!$dir = $column->getDir()) {
        return $this;
    }

    if ($column->getIndex() == 'orders_count') {
        $collection = $this->getCollection();
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->order("orders_count " . strtoupper($column->getDir()));
        return $this;
    }

    if ($column->getIndex() == 'orders_total') {
        $collection = $this->getCollection();
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->order("orders_total " . strtoupper($column->getDir()));
        return $this;
    }

    if ($column->getIndex() == 'last_order_date') {
        $collection = $this->getCollection();
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->order("last_order_date " . strtoupper($column->getDir()))
            ->order("last_order_date_filter " . strtoupper($column->getDir()));

        return $this;
    }

    return parent::_setCollectionOrder($column);
}
```

Changed method **_prepareCollection**

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addNameToSelect()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');


    /**
     *
     */
    $readAdapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $select = $readAdapter->select()
        ->from('sales_flat_order_grid')
        ->where('status=?', 'complete')
        ->columns(array(
                'orders_total' => new Zend_Db_Expr('CEIL(SUM(grand_total))'),
                'orders_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)'),
                'last_order_date' => new Zend_Db_Expr('MAX(created_at)'),
                'last_order_date_filter' => new Zend_Db_Expr('MAX(created_at)')
            )
        )->group('customer_id');

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('orders_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $select . ')')),
        'e.entity_id = orders_count.customer_id',
        array(
            'orders_count.orders_count',
            'orders_count.orders_total',
            'orders_count.last_order_date',
            'orders_count.last_order_date_filter'
        )
    );
    $collection->addFilterToMap('orders_count', 'orders_count.orders_count');
    $collection->addFilterToMap('orders_total', 'orders_count.orders_total');
    $collection->addFilterToMap('last_order_date', 'orders_count.last_order_date');
    /**
     *
     */


    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Added new columns to method **_prepareColumns**

```
$this->addColumn('last_order_date', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Order Date'),
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'align' => 'center',
        'index' => 'last_order_date',
        'gmtoffset' => true,
        'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_ordersLastOrderDateFilterCallBack'),
    ));

    $this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Total No. of Orders'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'width' => '40px',
        'index' => 'orders_count',
        'type' => 'number',
        'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_ordersCountFilterCallBack'),
        'sortable' => true,
    ));

    $this->addColumn('orders_total', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Total Sum. of Orders'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'width' => '40px',
        'index' => 'orders_total',
        'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_ordersTotalFilterCallBack'),
        'sortable' => true,
        'type' => 'currency',
        'currency_code' => 'UAH',
    ));
```

And added 3 new **Callback methods**, need for ***filters***

```
protected function _ordersCountFilterCallBack($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

    if (!isset($value['from'])) {
        $value['from'] = '';
    }

    if (!isset($value['to'])) {
        $value['to'] = '';
    }

    $from = ($value['from']) ? $value['from'] : 0;
    $to = ($value['to']) ? $value['to'] : 999999;
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->where("orders_count.orders_count >= $from AND  orders_count.orders_count <= $to");
    return $this;
}

protected function _ordersTotalFilterCallBack($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

    if (!isset($value['from'])) {
        $value['from'] = '';
    }

    if (!isset($value['to'])) {
        $value['to'] = '';
    }

    $from = ($value['from']) ? $value['from'] : 0;
    $to = ($value['to']) ? $value['to'] : 999999;
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->where("orders_count.orders_total >= $from AND  orders_count.orders_total <= $to");
    return $this;
}

protected function _ordersLastOrderDateFilterCallBack($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

    if (!isset($value['from'])) {
        $value['from'] = '';
    }

    if (!isset($value['to'])) {
        $value['to'] = '';
    }

    $from = ($value['from']) ? $value['from']->get('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') : $from = '2000-11-11 22:22:22';
    $to = ($value['to']) ? $value['to']->get('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') : $to = '2050-11-11 22:22:22';
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->where("orders_count.last_order_date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'");

    return $this;
}
```