# Magento - Last order date to customer grid

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, order-grid

I currently use XTENTO Enhanced Order Grid to add fields to the customer grid which works perfectly.

I need to however put in a column for the customers last order date.

I have searched however the only code I found also added in total number of orders and didn't specify the files I needed to edit.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can create / populate this field when an order is placed so I can show it in my grid?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to place a column (last placed order date by customer) under customer grid?

Comment: Hi, yes that's correct a column that shows all customers last order date

Comment: Please check my answer for same question
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/345410/9951

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following link:

- [Magento Customer Grid - Last Order Date](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37224/magento-customer-grid-last-order-date)
- http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-column-to-customers-grid-alternative-way/
- [Adding columns to customer grid using observer or overriding the customer grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5973/adding-columns-to-customer-grid-using-observer-or-overriding-the-customer-grid)

Comment: Thanks, the top one I have read and the issue is it adds two columns and I don't need the total number of orders column.

Do I add the code in that example to "app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php" ?

Comment: If you don't want to have both the columns, then delete the part `$this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Orders Count'),
        'index'     => 'orders_count',
    ));` from the function `_prepareColumns()`, that will do the job

Comment: Yes, you can add the codes in ***app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php***, but it's a better practise to overwrite the block from local scope