# Add "Total number order" & "Revenue" column to customer grid

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, customer, grid

I want to add 2 columns to customer gird:
***- Total number orders customer made.

- Total price of these orders.***

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First,please follow  @Amast post

[Magento Customer Grid - Last Order Date](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37224/magento-customer-grid-last-order-date)

You can get Customer total order from this link...

But for getting total price .use below code

```
     $total_pricesql ='SELECT sum(o.base_grand_total)'
            . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o'
            . ' WHERE o.customer_id = e.entity_id ';
        $expr = new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $total_pricesql . ')'); 

        $collection->getSelect()->from(null, array('total_price'=>$expr));
    $Totalsql ='SELECT COUNT(*)'
        . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o'
        . ' WHERE o.customer_id = e.entity_id ';
    $Totalsqlexpr = new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $Totalsql . ')'); 

    $collection->getSelect()->from(null, array('orders_count'=>$Totalsqlexpr));




$this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Orders Count'),
        'index'     => 'orders_count',
    ));

            $this->addColumn('total_price', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total),
                'index' => 'total_price,
                'type'  => 'currency',
                'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
            ));
```

### Edit:

You custom renderer class .Please check 
http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/ first.

From:

```
 $this->addColumn('total_price', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total),
                'index' => 'total_price,
                'type'  => 'currency',
                'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
            ));
```

**change:**

```
$this->addColumn('total_price',
array(
'header'=> Mage::helper('total_price')->__('Order total price'),
'index' => 'total_price',
'renderer'  => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Renderer_Red',// THIS IS WHAT THIS POST IS ALL ABOUT
));

}
```

**Add**

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
$value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
return '$'.$value.'</span>';

}
```

Comment: I don't need to add a tab for each customer to show there number total orders. I need to show that info on customer grid page.

Anyway, thanks you for your help :)

Comment: Great! It works perfectly, thanks you very much !. What should I do to add total number orders column to customer grid ?

Comment: question update ,please check...

Comment: Great!, your code work like a charm. But I have 1 question: the currency is wrong format: 1280.0000. how can I show as: €1280.00. Thanks you very much.

Comment: not possible using this code... need something else

Comment: I've tried to filter grid by total_price but I get this error : "Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/devmb/public_html/sites/dipacommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816". It seems that total_price is not real column in collection. What can I do to fix it :(

Comment: answer edited,please check all...