# Cannot filter new column calculated in custom customer grid

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, filter

I've just added 2 new columns to my grid that calculated total order & total price of them for customer grid:

Here is my _prepareCollection function:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id');

        // zend_debug::dump($collection->getData());die;
        $total_pricesql ='SELECT sum(o.base_grand_total)'
            . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o'
            . ' WHERE o.customer_id = e.entity_id ';
        $expr = new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $total_pricesql . ')'); 

        $collection->getSelect()->from(null, array('total_price'=>$expr));

        $totalsql ='SELECT COUNT(*)'
            . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o'
            . ' WHERE o.customer_id = e.entity_id ';
        $totalsqlexpr = new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $totalsql . ')'); 

        $collection->getSelect()->from(null, array('orders_count'=>$totalsqlexpr));
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

Here is my code to add 2 column to grid:

```
$this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Total Orders'),
            'index'     => 'orders_count',
            // 'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_roleFilter'),
        ));

        $this->addColumn('total_price', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total Sales'),
            'index' => 'total_price',
            'type'  => 'price',
            'currency_code' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
        ));
```

But when I tried to filter them, I got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/devmb/public_html/sites/dipacommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/A‌​bstract.php on line 816
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: have you check http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71728/add-total-number-order-revenue-column-to-customer-grid update

Comment: i've checked but "'currency_code' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCode()" has worked for me :). Anyway, your code is very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, you should definitely do these codes in resource models, not in blocks.
- Second, you should use a `joinLeft`, not `from`.
- Third, you need `GROUP BY` on your queries, since you're using `SUM` and `COUNT` aggregates..

Anyway, here's what you should do:

1. Modify `Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Customer_Collection` and add this method:

   ```
   public function addSalesInfoPerCustomer() {
   $this->getSelect()
       ->joinLeft(
           array('s' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(SELECT sum(o.base_grand_total) total_sales, COUNT(*) as order_count, customer_id'
               . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o'
               . ' GROUP BY customer_id)')),
           "s.customer_id = e.entity_id",
           array('total_sales', 'order_count')
       );
   }
   ```
2. On your `_prepareCollection` method, call `$collection->addSalesInfoPerCustomer();`
3. Call `addColumn` and take note of the column names `total_sales` and `order_count` (You need to modify your code to match these)

Comment: really nice suggested, but I've just tried and get that error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/devmb/public_html/sites/dipacommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php on line 67

Comment: I'm using magento 1.6 so I copy addSalesInfoPerCustomer() function to Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer.

Comment: Try again, I removed the `[` and used `array(` instead. It has something to do with PHP version, sorry.

Comment: I've tried again but this error still happen: Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/devmb/public_html/sites/dipacommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816