# Show customers last login in customer grid

Tags: admin, module, database, magento-1, customer-grid

Im trying to show the customers last login in the customer grid. (with data from the log_customer table)

To accomplish this, i created a Module with the neccesary Files.
With the help from these Links:

- [Adding columns to customer grid using observer or overriding the customer grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5973/adding-columns-to-customer-grid-using-observer-or-overriding-the-customer-grid)
- [Magento Customer Grid - Last Order Date](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37224/magento-customer-grid-last-order-date?rq=1)
- [magento add last login to customer grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933611/magento-add-last-login-to-customer-grid)
- [Magento Grid - sortering and filtering works incorrectly after joining flat table to EAV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369497/magento-grid-sortering-and-filtering-works-incorrectly-after-joining-flat-tabl)

I see the empty row in the Customer grid, but all my attempts didnt brought me to the solution.

[image: The empty column]

The Files

- `app\code\local\MyModule\ExtendCustomerGrid\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Grid.php`

---

```
    class MyModule_ExtendCustomerGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid { 
    protected function _prepareCollection() {
                        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
                                ->addNameToSelect()
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('last_login')
                                ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                                ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                                ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                                ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                                ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');



                    // Retrieve data from log_customer

                    $sql = '(SELECT MAX(login_at) 
                             FROM log_customer 
                             WHERE log_customer.customer_id = e.entity_id 
                             GROUP BY log_customer.customer_id)';
                    $expr = new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $sql . ')');

                    $collection->getSelect()->columns(array('last_login' => new Zend_Db_Expr($sql)));




                    $this->setCollection($collection);

                    return parent::_prepareCollection();

}

                protected function _prepareColumns() {
                    ...

                    $this->addColumn('last_login', array(
                        'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Letzte Anmeldung'),
                        'width' => '80',
                        'type' => 'datetime',
                        'align' => 'center',
                        'index' => 'login_at',
                        'filter_index' => '`c_log`.`login_at`',
                        'gmtoffset' => true
                    ));

                    ...

                    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('customer')->__('CSV'));
                    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', 

    Mage::helper('customer')->__('Excel XML'));
                        return parent::_prepareColumns();
                    }
     }
```

- `app\code\local\MyModule\ExtendCustomerGrid\etc\config.xml`

---

```
    <config>
        <modules>
            <MyModule_ExtendCustomerGrid>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </MyModule__ExtendCustomerGrid>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <blocks>
                <adminhtml>
                    <rewrite>
                        <customer_grid>MyModule__ExtendCustomerGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid</customer_grid><!-- rewrite the customer grid -->
                    </rewrite>
                </adminhtml>
            </blocks>
        </global>
    </config>
```

- `app\etc\modules\MyModule_ExtendCustomerGrid.xml`

---

```
    <config>
        <modules>
            <MyModule_ExtendCustomerGrid>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
                <depends>
                    <Mage_Customer /><!-- module should depend on Mage_Customer -->
                    <Mage_Adminhtml /><!-- module should depend on Mage_Adminhtml also -->
                </depends>
            </MyModule_ExtendCustomerGrid>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

Thx in advance

Comment: I've added  the 3 FIles that are involved.

Answer (score 2):

Working `_prepareCollection` method:

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->addNameToSelect()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('last_login')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

    $sql = '(SELECT MAX(logout_at) FROM log_customer WHERE log_customer.customer_id = e.entity_id GROUP BY log_customer.customer_id)';
    $collection->getSelect()->columns(array('last_login' => new Zend_Db_Expr($sql)));

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
}
```

As you can see, only change is

`return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();`

instead of

`return parent::_prepareCollection();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your sql as below

```
   protected function _prepareCollection() {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
                ->addNameToSelect()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('last_login')
                ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');




    // Retrieve data from log_customer

    $sql = '(SELECT MAX(logout_at) FROM log_customer WHERE log_customer.customer_id = e.entity_id GROUP BY log_customer.customer_id)';


    $collection->getSelect()->columns(array('last_login' => new Zend_Db_Expr($sql)));




    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns() {
    ...

   $this->addColumn('last_login', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Letzte Anmeldung'),
        'width' => '80',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'align' => 'center',
        'index' => 'last_login',        
        'gmtoffset' => true
    ));

    ...

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('customer')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Excel XML'));
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

becuase in your sql "login_max" not found and also spelling mistake at ce.entity_id

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick help Prashant, but my Customer Grid (last login) keeps still empty. I added the SQL you gave me and changed logout_at to login_at.

Comment: Updated answer try this it is working for me.

Comment: It made sense to me when i did compare the changes you made, but it is still the same. Empty Column... So the problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: use code for collection and grid column which i posted because it is working for me.

Comment: I did, but no values appear in the Grid :(

Comment: Using this code i have set column in customer grid you can check in image.Please recheck your code.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you are takin. I did copy/paste your code but there is still no value inside the  fields. I disabled all caches, cleared my browser cache and checked on firefox, chrome and safari.

Comment: Debug your grid file, exit in _prepareCollection() check other extension is not overriding your file.

Comment: What if customer logs, or all logs are disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You r getting totally blank rows or just "last login time" ?
Check out your Grid.php file and 
it looks like that prepareCollection method is fine.

Specify in layout.xml file if you haven't did ? or else you can specify in controllers file.

Comment: Hi Same. I get blank rows. No content. Under /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout there is no layout.xml File

Comment: your Grid.php file is okay. Share your controller file means indexAction or ListAction

Comment: I dont have a cotroller file . Only the  3 mentioned above. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: no need to add additional file.  Also confirm that you have enabled customer log Now to go System > Configuration > System > log and set Enable Log to Yes
  Finally, flush your Magento caches under System > Cache Management
  Magento should longer write logs to these tables

Comment: I looked into the System > log cleaning. It is disabled. Can you explain why it is neccesary to clear those tables? With the SQL Statement of @Prashant Valanda i get the Values correctly (in PhpMyAdmin)

Comment: i m not telling you to clear tables. Just enable them. If you enable Log to Yes then customer login logout time will save in table. if enable log is set to No then it wont save log for customer.

Comment: Turned the log cleaning on, and it didnt brought me any further.

Comment: After that i tried to disable my Module (System > Config > Advanced) and then the customer grid was not visible anymore. Turned it on and it came back. But the deserved values didnt want to show up.

Comment: Oh man do not disable Module's output, i have said enable log , Go to System-> config-> system ( not advanced ).

Comment: Dear Same, i did disable myModule just to see if it has any affects. Dont worry about that. I followed your advice and did activate the log cleaning -> on. After that i cleared caches, log out and logged in and checked on 3 browsers. Still no data in that row.