# Add (billing) company name to customer collection

Tags: collection, magento-1, customer-grid

I want to add the billing company name to the customer grid. I found [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5986/3089). To help me with the grid. But I can't seem to get the company name to appear.

Can anybody help me with this?

The observed event is `eav_collection_abstract_load_before`. The observer method:

```
public function eavCollectionAbstractLoadBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    if (!isset($collection) || !$collection instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection) return;

    /* @var $collection Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection */

    Mage::log( (string) $collection->getSelect() );

    // Add billing company here
    // $collection->addAttributeToSelect('billing_company');
}
```

The SQL the Mage:log gives:

```
    SELECT
  `e`.*,
  `at_prefix`.`value` AS `prefix`,
  `at_firstname`.`value` AS `firstname`,
  `at_middlename`.`value` AS `middlename`,
  `at_lastname`.`value` AS `lastname`,
  `at_suffix`.`value` AS `suffix`,
  CONCAT(IF(at_prefix.value IS NOT NULL AND at_prefix.value != '', CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(at_prefix.value)), ' '), ''),
         LTRIM(RTRIM(at_firstname.value)), ' ', IF(at_middlename.value IS NOT NULL AND at_middlename.value != '',
                                                   CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(at_middlename.value)), ' '), ''),
         LTRIM(RTRIM(at_lastname.value)),
         IF(at_suffix.value IS NOT NULL AND at_suffix.value != '', CONCAT(' ', LTRIM(RTRIM(at_suffix.value))),
            '')) AS `name`,
  `at_default_billing`.`value` AS `default_billing`,
  `at_billing_postcode`.`value` AS `billing_postcode`,
  `at_billing_city`.`value` AS `billing_city`,
  `at_billing_telephone`.`value` AS `billing_telephone`,
  `at_billing_region`.`value` AS `billing_region`,
  `at_billing_country_id`.`value` AS `billing_country_id`
FROM `iop_customer_entity` AS `e` LEFT JOIN `iop_customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_prefix`
    ON (`at_prefix`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_prefix`.`attribute_id` = '4')
  LEFT JOIN `iop_customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_firstname`
    ON (`at_firstname`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_firstname`.`attribute_id` = '5')
  LEFT JOIN `iop_customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_middlename`
    ON (`at_middlename`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_middlename`.`attribute_id` = '6')
  LEFT JOIN `iop_customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_lastname`
    ON (`at_lastname`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_lastname`.`attribute_id` = '7')
  LEFT JOIN `iop_customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_suffix`
    ON (`at_suffix`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_suffix`.`attribute_id` = '8')
  LEFT JOIN `iop_customer_entity_int` AS `at_default_billing`
    ON (`at_default_billing`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_default_billing`.`attribute_id` = '13')
  LEFT JOIN `iop_customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_postcode`
    ON (`at_billing_postcode`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND
       (`at_billing_postcode`.`attribute_id` = '30')
  LEFT JOIN `iop_customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_city`
    ON (`at_billing_city`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND (`at_billing_city`.`attribute_id` = '26')
  LEFT JOIN `iop_customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_telephone`
    ON (`at_billing_telephone`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND
       (`at_billing_telephone`.`attribute_id` = '31')
  LEFT JOIN `iop_customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_region`
    ON (`at_billing_region`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND (`at_billing_region`.`attribute_id` = '28')
  LEFT JOIN `iop_customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_country_id`
    ON (`at_billing_country_id`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND
       (`at_billing_country_id`.`attribute_id` = '27')
WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1')
```

For completion sake, the add column to grid oberver `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` with method:

```
public function coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $grid = $observer->getBlock();

    if (!$grid instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid) return;
    /** @var Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid $grid */

    $grid->addColumnAfter(
        'billing_company',
        array(
            'header' => 'company_name', //@todo translate
            'index' => 'billing_company',
        ),
        'name'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
            <observers>
                <{observer_name}>
                    <class>{namespace}_{module}/observer</class>
                    <method>beforeBlockToHtml</method>
                </{observer_name}>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
        <eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
            <observers>
                <{observer_name}>
                    <class>{namespace}_{module}/observer</class>
                    <method>beforeCollectionLoad</method>
                </{observer_name}>
            </observers>
        </eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

observer.php

```
<?php 
class Namespace_ModuleName_Model_Observer
{
    public function beforeBlockToHtml(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $grid = $observer->getBlock();

        /**
         * Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid
         */
        if ($grid instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid) {
            $grid->addColumnAfter(
                'billing_company',
                array(
                    'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Billing Company'),
                    'index'  => 'billing_company'
                ),
                'email'
            );
        }
    }

    public function beforeCollectionLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getCollection();
        if (!isset($collection)) {
            return;
        }

        /**
         * Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection
         */
        if ($collection instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection) {
            /* @var $collection Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection */
            $collection->joinAttribute('billing_company', 'customer_address/company', 'default_billing', null, 'left'); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The column remains empty :(

Comment: billing_company customer attribute or customer address attribute?

Comment: the billing_company column. Other (default) address data remains normally. Like the postal code and phone number.

Comment: updates ans pls check now