# magento 2 - How to add column to grid of customers in admin

Tags: magento2, customer, adminhtml

In magento 2, How to add column to grid of customers in admin ?
Please show me step by step if you can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding columns to customer grid using observer or overriding the customer grid](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5973/adding-columns-to-customer-grid-using-observer-or-overriding-the-customer-grid)

Comment: Hey @Dev! your link is for M1.7, I need for M2

Comment: for already existing column or add new column?

Comment: from same table or custom table

Comment: @ Rakesh, Yes, it's already existing column.

Comment: @ Sohel Rana, it's the attributes of customer.

Comment: what have you tried till now. ? You cannot ask to put up the entire code for you. You can ask for help if incase you are stuck somewhere

Comment: @Manashvi birla, I could not find place to customize, which has functions (_prepareCollection and _prepareColumns) is the same making for product.

Comment: If you want to add new column then you can make use of view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml (just a hint). check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748806/add-new-column-in-admin-product-grid-in-magento-2 for further reference.

Comment: This link only apply for product, customer is difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For add column to grid,

```
Go to Admin
```

Login with your user id,
Click on left navigation `Customers -> All Customers`

Customer grid page is display,
Now click on `columns button` at right top.

You have display list of columns name with checkbox.

Check/Tick the column you want to display in grid.

Now column are display in grid of customer list.

Thanks.

Comment: I would like hard code to default for grid, so how to do?