# Display custom attribute data in sales order grid view

Tags: grid, sales-order, ce-1.9.1.0, order-grid

I have created a module with the following observer that should pull the '`orderstatus_status_code`' custom attribute value from the `sales_flat_order` table through to the Sales Order Grid View;

```
<?php    
    class OrderSync_Model_Observer {    
        /**
         * Adds column to admin sales order grid
         *
         * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
         * @return OrderSync_Model_Observer
         */
        public function appendOrderSync($observer)
        {
            $block = $observer->getBlock();
            if (!isset($block)) {
                return $this;
            }

            if ($block->getType() == 'adminhtml/sales_order_grid') {
                /* @var $block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid */
                $block->addColumnAfter('ordersync_status_code', array(
                    'header'    => 'Order Sync Status',
                    'type'      => 'varchar',
                    'index'     => 'ordersync_status_code',
                    'filter_index'     => 'ordersync_status_code',
                ), 'status');
            }
        }
    }
```

This has correctly added the '**Order Sync Status**' column but no value is displaying where I know there is data in the table and I wondered if anyone can help to show me how to get the data there?

Comment: What Magento version?

Comment: Apologies, CE 1.9.1.0

Comment: Have you created filed "ordersync_status_code" only table sales_flat_order rigjht?

Comment: Please create same field in table "sales_flat_order_grid" and use your code

Answer (score 1):

Declare 2 observers in your `config.xml` file: one to add your column to the grid block and the other one to load data from the corresponding attribute:

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
            <observers>
                <{observer_name}>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>{namespace}_{module}/observer</class>
                    <method>beforeBlockToHtml</method>
                </{observer_name}>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
        <eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
            <observers>
                <{observer_name}>
                    <class>{namespace}_{module}/observer</class>
                    <method>beforeCollectionLoad</method>
                </{observer_name}>
            </observers>
        </eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

For your observer class-

```
class {Namespace}_{Module}_Model_Observer
{
    public function beforeBlockToHtml(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $grid = $observer->getBlock();

        /**
         * Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid
         */
        if ($grid instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid) {
            $grid->addColumnAfter(
                '{column_code}',
                array(
                    'header' => Mage::helper('{Module}_customer')->__('{{column_name}}'),
                    'index'  => '{column_code}'
                ),
                'entity_id'
            );
        }
    }

    public function beforeCollectionLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getCollection();
        if (!isset($collection)) {
            return;
        }

        /**
         * Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection
         */
        if ($collection instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection) {
            /* @var $collection Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection */
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('{attribute_code}');
        }
    }
}
```

Review following URL - 
[Adding columns to customer grid using observer or overriding the customer grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5973/adding-columns-to-customer-grid-using-observer-or-overriding-the-customer-grid)

Check answer by Arnaud AKA Narno

> If you will the shared URL solves your query, you can close this
>   question as it can have possible chances of getting closed due to
>   Duplicate